# Error after using Mac OS bless command: "no bootable device"

Tags: applescript

I've created an applescript to boot from snow leopard to lion, but the bless command is failing. Here's the command:

```
do shell script "bless -mount /Volumes/bootdrive/ -legacy -setBoot -nextonly" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

On reboot, I get the black screen with 'No bootable device' error. I've run the command directly in the terminal as root (rather than as an applescript) and have gotten the same result. And yes, I've triple-checked that the disk path I'm using is correct and is bootable.

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an appropriate setup to test with, but the `-legacy` option looks very suspicious to me. According to [the man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/bless.8.html), that's used to support BIOS-based operating systems, which OS X isn't. Try removing `-legacy` and see if it works better.

Comment: Thought I had tried that -- apparently not. That did the trick. Made my day :U)

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution**

The SIP was the first problem I've encountered on Big Sur. Turned it off looks like a bad idea. The second problem was target volumes list items doesn't have actions. Which make impossible to click on them via click or "click at" functions perhaps because of some new additional protections on Big Sur. Click with AST and other scripts also doesn't works due to new MacOS restrictions. The only way I found is using python click(but this leads to a slight delay while script selects target volume).

So here is a fully automated switching:

```
property targetVolume : "BOOTCAMP" # find name of required volume inside System Preference > Startup Disk
property passwordValue : "yourSystemPassword" # Can be empty

tell application "System Events"
    tell application "System Preferences"
        set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.startupdisk"
        activate
    end tell
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell window "Startup Disk"
            set volumePosition to {0, 0}
            set lockFound to false
            
            # Check if auth required
            set authButtonText to "Click the lock to make changes."
            if exists button authButtonText then
                click button authButtonText
                
                # Wait for auth modal
                set unlockButtonText to "Unlock"
                repeat
                    if (exists sheet 1) and (exists button unlockButtonText of sheet 1) then exit repeat
                end repeat
                
                # Autofill password if setted
                if passwordValue is not equal to "" then
                    set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 to passwordValue
                    click button unlockButtonText of sheet 1
                end if
                
                # Wait for auth success
                repeat
                    if exists button "Click the lock to prevent further changes." then exit repeat
                end repeat
            end if
            
            # Wait until loading volumes list
            repeat
                if exists group 1 of list 1 of scroll area 1 then exit repeat
            end repeat
            
            # Click on target volume (posible a slight delay because of shell script executing)
            repeat with m in (UI element of list 1 of scroll area 1)
                if (value of first static text of m = targetVolume) then
                    tell static text targetVolume of m
                        set volumePosition to position
                    end tell
                end if
            end repeat
            set volumePositionX to item 1 of volumePosition
            set volumePositionY to item 2 of volumePosition
            my customClick(volumePositionX, volumePositionY)
            
            click button "Restart…"
            
            # Wait for restart modal appears
            repeat
                if (exists sheet 1) and (exists value of first static text of sheet 1) then exit repeat
            end repeat
            
            click button "Restart" of sheet 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

# shell script to make click work on target volume
on customClick(x, y)
    do shell script " 

/usr/bin/python <<END

import sys

import time

from Quartz.CoreGraphics import * 

def mouseEvent(type, posx, posy):

          theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (posx,posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft)

          CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent)

def mousemove(posx,posy):

          mouseEvent(kCGEventMouseMoved, posx,posy);

def mouseclick(posx,posy):

          mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, posx,posy);

          mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseUp, posx,posy);

ourEvent = CGEventCreate(None); 

currentpos=CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);             # Save current mouse position

mouseclick(" & x & "," & y & ");

mousemove(int(currentpos.x),int(currentpos.y));      # Restore mouse position

END"
end customClick

on simpleEncryption(_str)
    set x to id of _str
    repeat with c in x
        set contents of c to c + 100
    end repeat
    return string id x
end simpleEncryption

on simpleDecryption(_str)
    set x to id of _str
    repeat with c in x
        set contents of c to c - 100
    end repeat
    return string id x
end simpleDecryption
```

You just need to change two properties **targetVolume** and **passwordValue**. Password can be empty and in that case you can provide it manually. Then just copy this script, paste it to the Script Editor and export via File -> Export -> file format - Application, select Run-only -> Save. You can do the same process for all systems you have, for example Big Sur 1, Big Sur 2, Bootcamp.